# Expo LocalAuthentication Biometrics Permissions

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, expo

SDK Version: 48.0.15
Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): Android & IOS

I am doing a Biometrics Login Flow and everything is pretty much straightforward. Just one question: **When I call authenticateAsync does this method handle the case when User did not grand FaceID permissions to the application?** Or these permissions are already given by using Expo.

Note: I saw some applications that when I activate Biometrics Login a popup to give permission appears that will redirect me to the Device settings to grant permission. From what I’ve read, Expo handles this case, but I want to check this here.

I have not deployed my application, just tested it with the expo emulator on my IPhone 8. Everything worked fine, the Fingerprint login did not need extra permissions.
I just want to make sure there is not something I am missing

Comment: You need to post some code. Pls read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask